# How do I add URL link for a testcase number in CAPL?

Tags: capl

I am trying to add URL link to testcase numbers using CAPL. Is it possible through CAPL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot add URL link to the testcase numbers. 
I suppose you are talking about the report html files of a testcase.

Although, speaking of a html formatting, you can *hack the report file*, what is generated, you find the testcase number and insert html code formatting so when clicking it, will bring you to the link you need.

Or, you can create your own XLST stlyesheet (which will add custom links to anywhere you want) , and select it as the option for Test Report Generation in the Test Nodes Configuration menu. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks VioletVynil

Comment: Also found this command from Vector help.....TestReportAddExternalRef : Adds an external reference to the report (URL, DOORS or eASEE link), which appears as a link in the HTML report. Can be used in test cases (test case functions), test groups or in MainTest functions.

Comment: That function requires special DOORs extension or Vteststudio license to work as far as I know.